# Is jQuery cascade? If not, why doesn't my code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to make a div move in jQuery (I know almost nothing about) and it works unless I don't try to affect one element with another.

What I want is for #bodywrapperfloat to move when #clicken is clicked.

I can make #clicken move when I clik it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clicken').click(function() {               
     $(this).animate({
       marginLeft: '-500px'        
      }, 400);
});                                          
});
</script>
```

I thought I could change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clicken').click(function() {               
     $('#bodywrapperfloat').animate({
       marginLeft: '-500px'        
      }, 400);
});                                          
});
</script>
```

but then nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the full HTML:

```
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;CHARSET=ISO-8859-2">
<meta http-equiv="Generator" content="TigerII MiniPad (C)2001">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clicken').click(function() {               
     $('#bodywrapperfloat').animate({
       marginLeft: '-500px'        
      }, 400);
});                                          
});
</script>



 <title>ThinkOne Initiative</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="headergreen">
<div id="headerwrapper">
<div style="font-weight:500; display:inline-block;">think</div><div style="font-weight:300; display:inline-block;">One</div>
<div id="contactlink"><a href="#">contact</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bodywrapperfixed">
<div id="bodywrapperfloat">
<table id="ramka">
     <tr>
          <td>random text</td>
          <td><div id="bodywrapper">
<center>
<div id="texten"><div style="font-weight:300; display:inline-block;">Introducing the all-in-one entertainment system.</div><div style="font-weight:500; display:inline-block;">&nbsp;For everyone.</div></div>


<div id="textpl"><div style="font-weight:300; display:inline-block;">Przedstawiamy zintegrowany system rozrywki.</div><div style="font-weight:500; display:inline-block;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Dla wszystkich.</div></div>


<img src="imgs/xboxone.png">


<div id="texten"><div style="font-weight:300; display:inline-block;">Choose your version of the story:</div></div>


<div id="textpl"><div style="font-weight:300; display:inline-block;">Wybierz swoją wersją opowieści:</div></div>




<table id="linki">
<tr>
<td><div id="clicken">en</td>
<td><div id="clickpl">pl</td>
</tr></table>
</center>
</div></td>
          <td>random text</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here's the link:

http://ingame.lh.pl/thinkone/

Comment: Try to set `margin-left` with CSS and see if it has any affect

Comment: you have positioned your div with absolute, the jQuery code works its your markup and CSS that doesnt react to its parents. You seem to have elements with the same ID but thats not why the code doesnt work

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had no #bodywrapperfloat iin css. Aram, Thanks for pointing me with the right direction. Post it as answer and I will marki it as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Hm, this works. I can't see any failures

http://jsfiddle.net/xmbhA/

Comment: If you figured the right answer, you should post, and accept it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your content is inside `position:absolute` and your `bodywrapperfloat` is static and cannot be the nearest ancestor, so when it moves, your contents won't move with it.
In your case, when you move the `body`, the contents will move.

Add `position:relative` to your `bodywrapperfloat` to make it the nearest ancestor. So when it moves, your contents inside `position:absolute` move along with it.

```
<div id="bodywrapperfloat" style="position:relative">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "bodywrapper" div that holds most of the content is "position:absolute", try making your "bodywrapperfloat" div "position:relative". You will then get some action at least.